# Microservices - Storing user data in separate database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, microservices

I am building a microservice that has two separate services: a user service and a comments service. The user service stores the user details like email, first/last name job title, etc, and the comments service stores all comments made by the user.

In the UI, I need to populate the comments (via a REST API) and show the first/last name, email, and job title of the user.

Is it recommended that we store all these user details in the comments database?

If yes, then every time a user changes their details first/last name or job title then I will have to update their details in all the comments (I don't think this is a good idea )

If no, then if I store just the userid in the comments DB, how am I supposed to get the user details for each comment? Let's say we want to show 20 comments per page in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, challenge architecture. Let's assume that the both services in the question are part of a larger ecosystem of microservices that all make use of the user information. Else separation will most certainly be overengineered. But from the word "comments" we can at least guess that there is at least one other class of objects, that is the things being commented. So let's assume a "user service" is a meaningful crumb to break out into a microservice, because at least some other crumbs get the necessary weight to justify the microservice breakup.

In that case I suggest the following strategy:

Second, implement an abstraction layer into your comments service right away so that most of the code will not have to care about where the user comes from (i.e. don't join or $lookup). This is also a great opportunity for local testing, because you can just create a collection with the data you need and run service level integration tests against it.

Third, for integration with the user service, get the data from there via API (which should support bulk data selection in any case) every time you need it. Because you have the abstraction layer, you can add caching, cache timeout and displacement strategies and whatever you may need below this abstraction without caring in the main portion of the code. Add such on an as needed basis. Keep it simple.

Fourth, when things really go heavyweight and you have to care with tens of thousands of users, tons of comments and many requests per second the comments service could, still below the abstraction, implement an upfront replication pattern to get the full user database locally. This will usually be done based on an asynchronous message being sent by the user service to all subscribers when something changes in te user base. When it suits the subscribers (i.e. the comment service), they can trigger full or (from time to time) delta replication of the changes. Suitable collections will be already in place from what you did for caching. And it will probably be considerably less info you need in the comments service, than is stored in user service (let alone the hashed password, other login options or accounting information).

Fifth, should you still hit performance challenges, you can break the abstraction for the few cases you need to and do the join or $lookup.

Follow the steps in order, and stop as soon as the overall assembly works fine. Every step adds considerable complexity, and when you don't need it, don't implement it.